# Views Data Export not showing data export display option in view

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I installed [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module on a Drupal 7.50 site and it works beautifully. I am trying to incorporate it now into a new website (which happens to be 7.54). I have cleared all the Drupal caches as well as the browser cache and have checked that the module is enabled. I also have [Views Excel Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls) extension installed and enabled on both sites.

I'm completely stumped that this works perfectly on one site and not working on another.[image: First site, data export is a display option]. [image: Second site it is not an option].

Update: I thought I checked the versions, as I installed them on the same day, but somehow, the one on the site that works is an older version (3.1 vs. 3.2).

I tried uninstalling it and installing the [older version](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) but it didn't resolve the issue. I also checked permissions but there aren't permissions for this module.

Here is the conversation on [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1910006) with no resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had installed the [Views Excel Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls) module *first*. I had to uninstall both modules and then reinstall them in the correct order: [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) first and then [Views Excel Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls). This solved the issue for me!